Proving that Intervals are connected in $\Bbb R$ using continuous functions into $\{0,1\}$
I have come up with a proof for the fact that Intervals are connected sets in $\Bbb R$, that utilizes an equivalent definition of connected sets. Namely:

Definition. A topological space $X$ is called connected if every continuous function $f: X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ st. $\{0,1\}$ is discrete, is constant.

Question. As I have only every encountered proofs using a separation argument, I'd like to know whether my proof is correct, or if there are any holes in my logic. The main point I am unsure about is with my argumentation that the preimages are not open, that is the only step that to me seems to majorly deviate from all of the other proofs I've seen.
Proof. Since closed intervals are homeomorphic by dilation and translation, and connectedness is a topological property, it is enough to show that this holds for the interval $[0,1]$. I will also only prove that $[0,1]$ is connected, as the connectedness of half-open and open intervals follows from countable unions of closed intervals, which is an argument I have seen before.
Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ a non-constant function st. w.l.o.g $f(0)=0$. Further let $x := \inf\{ y \in [0,1]\ |\ f(y) = 1 \}$. We can distinguish two cases:

If $f(x) = 0$, let $A:= f^{-1}(0)$ and $\varepsilon >0$. By definition of the infimum, $\exists y \in (x, x + \varepsilon)\cap [0,1]$ st. $f(y) = 1$. In other words $(x-\varepsilon, x+ \varepsilon)\cap [0,1] \not \subseteq A$ which means that $A$ cannot be open in $[0,1]$ (since open balls form a fundamental system of open neighbourhoods around $x$). Therefore $f$ cannot be continuous.

If $f(x) = 1$, then $x>0$ and so $\forall \varepsilon > 0\ \forall y \in (x-\varepsilon, x)\cap [0,1] : f(x) = 0$. Analogously, this means that $B := f^{-1}(1)$ is not open as for every $\varepsilon>0: (x-\varepsilon, x+ \varepsilon)\cap [0,1] \not \subseteq B$. Therefore $f$ cannot be continuous.


Therefore by contraposition, every continuous function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is constant, and $[0,1]$ is connected $\square$.
Thank you in advance!

What is your question?

From the solution-verification tag description: 'For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.' Please identify a particular step you want us to look at.

@BenSteffan I think the main point I am unsure about is with my argumentation that the preimages are not open, that is the only step that to me seems to majorly deviate from all of the other proofs I've seen. It feels correct to me, which is why I'm posting it in the first place, but I've missed small details in past proofs that messed me up.

The part you are struggling with can be understood from a consequence of the definition of a base for a topology. In particular:

$\mathscr B$ is a base for $X$ iff whenever $G$ is an open set in $X$ and $p\in G$, there is some $B\in\mathscr B$ such that $p\in B\subset G$.

This quote can be found in Willard's General Topology, page 38, just after definition 5.1.
Now to the problem you are dealing with. In the first case it is proved that there exists some $x\in A$ such that, for any $\varepsilon>0$, the basic open $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ is never contained in $A$. However, any basic open of $[0,1]$ $G$ that contains $x$, has to contain a basic open of the form $B=(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, for a sufficiently small $\delta>0$ (again, because $G$ is open and $B$ is basic, and so they have to satisfy the property I cited from Willard's book).
In the end, the fact that no basic open centered at $x$ is contained in $A$ means no basic open is contained in $A$, and thus $A$ is not open in $[0,1]$. The same reasoning applies to $B$ in the second case.

The proof strikes me as correct and nicely written.

Here's a few more things that could make it even better (in my opinion): First of all, note that $f^{-1}(1)$ is a closed subset of $[0, 1]$ and therefore compact, so the infimum you're taking is in fact a minimum (I assume you know this from real analysis). This implies the case $f(x) = 0$ never occurs and you can drop it entirely.
On that note, working with a function $f$ feels slightly artificial: I would simply say something like "Let $C \sqcup D = [0, 1]$ be a partition of $[0, 1]$ into disjoint nonempty clopens" and work with the sets directly instead of referring back to preimages since relying on $f$ doesn't provide any additional benefits.
What you're really saying then is that having a minimum or maximum in $(0, 1)$ is incompatible with being open, which you may or may not have explicitly seen in a real analysis course (or similar), or you could even make it into its own little lemma.

Thank you for your response. May I ask why exactly $f^{-1}(1)$ being closed follows directly from the definition of $f$?

@clorx $f$ is continuous, ${1} \subset {0, 1}$ is closed, and preimages of closed subsets under continuous maps are closed :)

@clorx To drive home the point: there's almost no difference between a decomposition into nonempty disjoint clopens like in my answer and a function $f$ as in your question: given $C \sqcup D = [0, 1]$, you get a continuous function $f\colon [0, 1] \to {0, 1}$ by letting $f(c) = 0$ for all $c \in C$ and $f(d) = 1$ for all $d \in D$. Conversely, given such an $f$, you recover a partition into clopens via $C = f^{-1}(0)$ and $D = f^{-1}(1)$. I'd recommend thinking this through once if any step here seems unclear.

Ah right, I didn't take it as a suggestion to rewrite this as a proof by contradiction, which confused me. Thanks :) Furthermore, I agree with your assessment that using a partition argument seems more natural, the point of this proof was to familiarize myself more with this alternative definition.
